# How can I do a "Fastball Special" to throw my ally at an enemy?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e, throwing-things, mutants-and-masterminds

I, being a fairly typical Powerhouse, want to chuck my friends at enemies so they can do a Slam Attack (or is it a Charge Attack? Whatever makes you use movement speed for damage). How would I go about doing this?

I can't find an official ruling for it.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the caveat that Green Ronin only counts the *Hero's Handbook* as core rules, the *[Power Profiles: Strength Powers](https://greenroninstore.com/collections/mutants-masterminds-third-edition/products/mutants-and-masterminds-power-profile-strength-powers-pdf)* supplement suggests:

> Lastly, a strong enough character can throw another character as a makeshift weapon! If the other character is a willing partner, this is a standard action for the thrower, who makes a ranged attack check to put the thrown character on-target. The thrown character gets to make either a charge or a slam attack using the throwing distance rank as speed rank (*Deluxe Hero's Handbook*, page 246 and 250, respectively), and the thrown character’s initiative moves to directly after the thrower's.

Comment: Thanks! What is the difference between a Charge and a Slam Attack?

Comment: A Charge attack lets you combine movement in a straight line and an attack into a single Standard action at a -2 penalty. A Slam attack is a special case of a Charge attack where you specifically impact them with your own body, which may add additional damage based on your movement, but also means you have to save against half of the damage rank.